# Copy value from text field to select dropdown

Tags: jquery

I want to copy value of input fields to my drop down using jQuery.
I have four option fields here with respective ids, when user enters any text on following field my drop down get value from it in real time .

My code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>option a</label>
<input type="text" id="opa" size="30" class="text-input" />
<br>
<label>option b</label>
<input type="text" id="opb" size="30" class="text-input" />
<br>
<label>option c</label>
<input type="text" id="opc" size="30" class="text-input" />
<br>
<label>option d</label>
<input type="text" id="opd" size="30" class="text-input" />
<br>


<input type="text" id="a1" name="">

<select name="ra" class="form-control" id="ra">
  <option value="" >---Select right option ---</option>
  <option id="a" ></option>
  <option id="b" ></option>
  <option id="c" ></option>
  <option id="d"  ></option>
</select>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far using jQuery? Please post it's code as well. @HamzaMustafa

Comment: i dont have so many idea about jquerey ,                        $("#ra").change(function(){
    $("#opa").val($(this).val("#a1"));
});

Comment: I would strongly suggest you to learn the basics of jQuery. Here are few resources for the same: [jQuery Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/index.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code below to achive what you want.

```
$("input[id^=op]").keyup(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("op","");
  $("#ra #" + id).val($(this).val()).text($(this).val());
})
```

**Note** I've didn't noticed that it was marked as duplicate before I pressed submit to the answer, but I'll leave it anyway

```js
$("input[id^=op]").keyup(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("op","");
  $("#ra #" + id).val($(this).val()).text($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>option a</label>
<input type="text" id="opa" size="30"  class="text-input" />
<br>
<label>option b</label>
<input type="text" id="opb" size="30"  class="text-input" />
<br>
<label>option c</label>
<input type="text" id="opc" size="30"  class="text-input" />
<br>
<label>option d</label>
<input type="text" id="opd" size="30"  class="text-input" />
<br>


<select name="ra" class="form-control" id="ra">
              <option value="" >---Select right option ---</option>
              <option id="a" ></option>
              <option id="b" ></option>
              <option id="c" ></option>
              <option id="d"  ></option>
             </select>
```

Comment: above code is not working sir

Comment: What do you mean that its not working, check the example

Comment: perfect solution

Comment: @ImranAhmadShahid Thanks

Comment: when i fill input fields , i got nothing under drop down sir

Comment: Have you made sure to take all my code, AND have you made sure you have included jquery in your project

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I'm not sure why experts like you and who has immense experience are promoting such questions in which the OP hasn't even done proper research in finding the solution.

Comment: now its working thank u so much , am such an idiot

Comment: @HamzaMustafa love to know why you removed my answer as accepted

Comment: oh man take it easy ! it was by mistake <3 Peace

Answer (score 1):

I create the following fiddle to update option text and value on keyup event:

```js
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#' + id[id.length - 1]).text(this.value);
  $('#' + id[id.length - 1]).val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>option a</label>
<input type="text" id="opa" size="30" class="text-input" />
<br>
<label>option b</label>
<input type="text" id="opb" size="30" class="text-input" />
<br>
<label>option c</label>
<input type="text" id="opc" size="30" class="text-input" />
<br>
<label>option d</label>
<input type="text" id="opd" size="30" class="text-input" />
<br>


<input type="text" id="a1" name="">

<select name="ra" class="form-control" id="ra">
  <option value="" >---Select right option ---</option>
  <option id="a" ></option>
  <option id="b" ></option>
  <option id="c" ></option>
  <option id="d"  ></option>
</select>
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: @HamzaMustafa What exactly is not working ? There is an error in console? Can you please be more specific ?

Comment: when i fill four input fields , i want there values on drop down , thats what i want only

Comment: @HamzaMustafa This is what the code above does.

Comment: i seriosuly dont know why its not even working here , tho i include jquerey library properly

Comment: @AlexChar I'm not sure why experts like you and who has immense experience(both in the Industry and IN STACKOVERFLOW as well) are promoting such questions in which the OP hasn't even done proper research in finding the solution!